# Crash in [OAMutableURLRequest parameters]

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, oauth, authentication

I am trying to figure out why my app is crashing when trying to log on with twitter credentials. The crash does not happen every time, but when it does the stack trace looks like this:

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x33abc8bf __exceptionPreprocess + 163 
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x31ade1e5 objc_exception_throw + 33
2 CoreFoundation 0x33a14275 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 165
3 -[OAMutableURLRequest parameters] (OAMutableURLRequest.m:241)
4  -[OAMutableURLRequest _signatureBaseString] (OAMutableURLRequest.m:179)
5  -[OAMutableURLRequest prepare] (OAMutableURLRequest.m:133)
```

Has anyone experienced this before?
TIA

ps. OAMutableURLRequest is a 3rd party library I am using. The problem appears to be index out of bounds, has anyone else had such a problem with this library?

Answer (score 0):

if it's an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, you've over-released or under-retained something. If you're in ARC, you need to either weak or strong type it depending on your code.